# Difference - Firewall Vs IDS (Intrusion Detection System)?

Tags: firewalls, ids

How firewalls differ from IDS ( Intrusion Detection System ) ? What are the differences between them ?

Comment: Though its a duplicate question as already asked.. I unable to delete this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Wikipedia on [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)):

> In computing, a firewall is a network security system that monitors and controls the incoming and outgoing network traffic based on predetermined security rules

Taken from Wikipedia on [IDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system):

> An intrusion detection system (IDS) is a device or software application that monitors a network or systems for malicious activity or policy violations.

**About the difference between both of them:**

The main difference is that firewall preforms actual actions such as blocking and filtering while and IDS just detects and alert a system administrator. [Here](http://www.omnisecu.com/security/infrastructure-and-email-security/difference-between-firewall-and-intrusion-detection-system.php) is a small article talking about the differences for further reading.